# Reading out integers of Application.Current.Properties in WPF / Regex

Tags: c#, regex, wpf

I'm relatively new to coding. Currently doing an project with WPF and I'm struggling with loading data out of  Application.Current.Properties.

In total I have 6 Windows (1 Starting, 4 Windows for Settings, 1 for the Final presentation). I have to save data in the 4 setting-windows and load them in the final window. For 3 windows it works, but having problems with the last one.

**The mistake (I assume) must be from how I read and/or save the Data in the second window.** When I check the data before saving it into App.Current.Properties it's still correct. As soon as I load it in the final window, the values are all 0.

thank you for any suggestions!

Example of whats actually working:

Save Data:

```
object timecap = ForTimeTimecap.SelectedValue;
Application.Current.Properties["Timecap"] = timecap;
```

Load Data:

```
timecapString = Application.Current.Properties["Timecap"].ToString();
int timecap = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(timecapString, @"\d+").Value);
```

---

**Returns all Values with 0:**

Store Data: (Window 1)

```
object work = ComboBoxWork.SelectedValue;
Application.Current.Properties["WorkSeconds"] = work;
```

Load Data: (Window 2)

```
workSecondsString = Application.Current.Properties["WorkSeconds"].ToString();
int workSeconds = Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(workSecondsString, @"\d+").Value);
```

Also if you have a more elegant way to store the loaded data into the integer, Im open for suggestions. Implicit and explicit converting doenst work. WPF always gives me errors as soon as i start the app.

Edit:
The items in the Combobox are added via c#:

```
    for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
    {
        ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
        item.Text = i + " Min.";
        item.Value = i;
        ForTimeTimecap.Items.Add(item);
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing this string parsing at all, instead of storing and retrieving the desired type simply by casting to it? E.g. like `int x = (int)Application.Current.Properties["WorkSeconds"];`

Comment: I get the error: System.InvalidCastException by using this

Comment: Then tell us what type it actually is that you store. What is `ComboBoxWork.SelectedValue`? Have you set the SelectedValuePath of the ComboBox?

Comment: So far I stored an object (I assumed App.Current.Properties returns an obj anyways). But I havent set the SelectedValuePath of the Combobox. Do I just set it to "int"?

Comment: and for the comboboxitems i used:
            for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
            {
                ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
                item.Text = i + " Min.";
                item.Value = i;
                ForTimeTimecap.Items.Add(item);
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could access the `Value` property of your ComboboxItems by setting `SelectedValuePath="Value"` on the ComboBox.

Then `ComboBoxWork.SelectedValue` would return the integer Value of the selected item:

```
int work = (int)ComboBoxWork.SelectedValue;
```

This requires that `Value` is a public property, not a field of the ComboboxItem class.

---

However, a much "more elegant" approach would be not to have ComboboxItems at all.

Instead, use `int` items directly. Declare an ItemTemplate like

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxWork">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0} Min.}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

and fill the ComboBox with integers:

```
ComboBoxWork.ItemsSource = Enumerable.Range(0, 16);
```

Now `SelectedItem` will give you an integer:

```
int work = (int)ComboBoxWork.SelectedItem;
```

that you store like

```
Application.Current.Properties["WorkSeconds"] = work;
```

and retrieve like

```
int work = (int)Application.Current.Properties["WorkSeconds"];
```

Comment: I'm still editing. I just realized that you declared your own ComboboxItem type. Don't do that. Follow the "better approach".